# knockOut Refreshing a Databinding With Mapping

Tags: knockout.js

I have a viewmodel that has a knockoutObservableArray of the type BatchHistoryViewModel

It is being created successfully in the constuctor using the following mapping options

```
var mappingOptions = {
            'batchHistories': {
                create: function (options) {
                    return new BatchHistoryViewModel(options.data, dataContext);
                },
                key: function (batchHistory) {
                    return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(batchHistory.Id);
                }
            }
```

that works just fine and the observable array displays correctly in a table on the DOM

Now, when I am trying to run an update function to get the same data from the same source it is not updating the DOM
I can watch the observable in the console and see that it is being updated with the correct data, but it does not update on the page

here is my refresh function

```
    refresh() {
        var self = this;

        $.when(self.dataContext.getBatchHistories(0, "Any"))
            .done(function (refreshedData) {
                var mappingOptions = {
                    'batchHistories': {
                        create: function (options) {
                            return new BatchHistoryViewModel(options.data, null);
                        },
                        key: function (batchHistory) {
                            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(batchHistory.Id);
                        }
                    }
                };

                self = ko.mapping.fromJS(refreshedData, mappingOptions);
```

and here is the what the .net MVC Controller is returning

```
        var batchHistories =
            new
            {
                batchHistories =
                    this.consoleRepository.GetBatchHistories(fromDate, status).ToList()
                        .Select(batchHistory => new
                                                {
                                                    Id = batchHistory.Id,
                                                                            DataMartName = batchHistory.DataMartName,
                                                                            Name = batchHistory.Name,
                                                                            LoadType = batchHistory.LoadType,
                                                                            BatchDefinitionId = batchHistory.BatchDefinitionId,
                                                                            SsisExecutionId = batchHistory.SsisExecutionId,
                                                                            StatusId = batchHistory.StatusId,
                                                                            Status = batchHistory.Status.Status,
                                                                            StartDateTime = batchHistory.StartDateTime.SafeToString(),
                                                                            EndDateTime = batchHistory.EndDateTime.SafeToString(),
                                                })
                        .ToList()
            };


        return this.Json(batchHistories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I have tried it with or without the mapppingOptions on the fromJS, and I get the same result.

Any ideas? please ask if more code will help. I didn't want to overload the question with too much unless it was needed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was doing it wrong this was the correct way to apply the mappings

```
 ko.mapping.fromJS(refreshedData, self );
```